# Have JavaScript send returned values to two inputs elements

Tags: javascript

I am trying to add a section of code (shown below) to have my audio book picker supply an audio file name, as well as displaying the chapter and chapter number.

How can I make my added code send the second set of returned values to the input field with the id='audio', just as it sends return values to the input with the id='chapter-picker'?

```
var chapterPicker = myApp.picker({
      input: '#chapter-picker',
      rotateEffect: true,
      formatValue: function (picker, values) {
          return values[0] + ' ' + values[1];
      }, 

      //Start of what I am trying to add
      input: '#audio',
      rotateEffect: true,
      formatValue: function (picker, values) {
          return values[0] + values[1] + '.mp3';
      }
      //End of what I am trying to add 

      cols: [
          {
              textAlign: 'left',
              values: ['Genesis', 'Exodus', 'Leviticus'],
              onChange: function (picker, book) {
                  if(picker.cols[1].replaceValues){
                      picker.cols[1].replaceValues(chapters[book]);
                  }
              }
          },
          {
              values: chapters.Genesis,
              width: 160,
          },
      ]
  });
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking, could you clarify?  What isn't working in the code above?

Comment: Everything works in the code before I add the section shown between comments above. When I add that code, the return values from my added code get displayed in the HTML input with the id='audio', but the section of code above does not work (i.e. nothing gets sent to the id='chapter-picker'. I want both to happen. Thanks for looking at this.

Comment: I don't know what the function `picker` does, so I can't say how to change how it works.  Can you post the code for picker?

Comment: Thanks Russbear, here is a full working example if it helps. http://www.idangero.us/framework7/docs-demos/picker.html. Of course the code of picker is in the referenced framwork7.js file. I am using the "dependent values" picker.

Answer (score 0):

`input: '#chapter-picker'` is not being called because you are overwriting the `input` field with `input: '#audio'`. A JSON object cannot have two values for the same key.

From reading the docs on F7, the picker does not appear to support modifying two separate fields.  What you could do, is some fun thing where you have two HTMLElements with the same ID, one parses out the response from picker one way, and the other the other way.  But that's just off the top of my head.

You could also try putting an array into "inputs".  But I have no idea if that will work.

Comment: Russ, thank you very much for your time. An array works in "inputs", but I don't know how to send a different value to each of the input fields listed there. I will find a way to manipulate the value the existing input field. Thanks again!